# controller get html date by ajax

Tags: java, html, ajax, model-view-controller

in my html I need to enter a date value, afterthat, I am going to send the date through ajax to my MVC controller which connected with the database to get the record by date. However, I don't know how to send the date to my controller

Ajax in getData():

```
   $.ajax({ 
                        url: 'send'
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {date= $('#date').val,}
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                        success: function(resp) {
                          //do something
                        },


                        error: function(err) {
                           //error
                        }
                    });
```

get the date from user:

```
 <input type="date" id="date" placeholder="date" onkeyup="getData()">
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
     public List<Object> send(
            @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Date date) throws Exception {
                // do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I see lot's of issues here.

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '//controller action url',   // Missed the comma here
  type: 'POST',                    // Changed to post
  data: {"date": $('#date').val},    // Your syntax was wrong here
  contentType: "application/json", // Simplified this. Not need but I just prefer it this way.
  success: function(resp) {
      //do something
  },
  error: function(err) {
      //error
  }
});
```

Assuming that the controller action is something like:

```
public ActionResult Send(DateTime date){

}
```

Comment: what is the syntax for sending data in ajax

Comment: @Lucy Above you are using `=` when you should be using `:` as seen in my answer